# Does anyone have a PowerShell script that starts and stops aws ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

Does anyone have a PowerShell script that starts and stops aws ec2 instances?

param
(
[string] $Filter = "xxxxx*"
)

$CurrentDate = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd.0.0")

$instances = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @(@{name = 'tag:Name'; values = "xxxx"})  Start-EC2Instance $_.instances.instanceid

Answer (score 0):

Check out this cmdlet by AWS: "Start-EC2Instance Cmdlet", https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Start-EC2Instance.html

And in extension, have a look at the PowerShell Gallery to understand the AWS tools for PowerShell: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSPowerShell.NetCore/4.1.11.0